Angular SignalStore -> 2 Arrays
i have a SignalStore with 2 Arrays and 2 API Calls. Can i combine the 2 Arrays to 1 and can get the Data? So that i can use PVVormat.[0]. and PVVormonat.[1] with the data from the 2 API Calls?
export const AktuellerMonatStore = signalStore(
  withState(monatGesamt),
  withRequestStatus(),
  withMethods((store, dbService = inject(DBService)) => ({
    loadDaten: rxMethod<void>(
      pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          patchState(store, setPending());
          return dbService.getMonatGesamt('' + aktJahr + '', '' + monat + '').pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (pvVorjahr) =>
                patchState(store, { pvVorjahr }, setFulFilled()),
              error: (error: {message:string}) => {
                patchState(store, setError(error.message));
              }
            })
          )
        })
      )
    ),
    loadDatenVorjahr: rxMethod<void>(
      pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          patchState(store, setPending());
          return dbService.getMonatGesamt('' + aktJahr + '', '' + monat + '').pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (pvVormonat) =>
                patchState(store, { pvVormonat }, setFulFilled()),
              error: (error: {message:string}) => {
                patchState(store, setError(error.message));
              }
            })
          )
        })
      )
    )
  }))

Thx

You should crate a store with entities, see this article on Medium
Your store should looks like:
export interface IItem {
    id: number, 
    name: string
}


export const ItemsStore = signalStore(
        // {providedIn: 'root'},
        withState({isLoading: false}),
        withEntities({entity: type<IItem>(), collection: 'collection1'}),
        withEntities({entity: type<IItem>(), collection: 'collection2'}),

        withComputed((store) => ({
            getCollection1AndCollection2: computed(() => {
                return [...store.collection1Entities(), ...store.collection2Entities()];
            }),
        })),
        withMethods((store, dataService = inject(DataService)) => ({
            getCollection1: rxMethod<void>(
                pipe(
                    tap(() => patchState(store, {isLoading: true})),
                    switchMap( () => {
                        return dataService.getCollection1FromServer().pipe(
                            tapResponse({
                                next: (items: IItem[]) => {
                                    patchState(store, setEntities(items, {collection: 'collection1'}))
                                },
                                error: console.error,
                                finalize: () => patchState(store, {isLoading: false}),
                            })
                        )
                    })
                )
            ),
            getCollection2: rxMethod<void>(
                pipe(
                    tap(() => patchState(store, {isLoading: true})),
                    switchMap(book => {
                        return dataService.getCollection2FromServer().pipe(
                            tapResponse({
                                next: (items: IItem[]) => {
                                    patchState(store, setEntities(items, {collection: 'collection2'}))
                                },
                                error: console.error,
                                finalize: () => patchState(store, {isLoading: false}),
                            })
                        )
                    })
                )
            ),
        }))
    );


then you can use it on component or wherever else like:
@Component(...)
export class AComponent {
   private itemsStore = inject(ItemsStore);

   listOfAllItems: Item[] = this.itemsStore.getCollection1AndCollection2();
}

